# How to get the old Panel 0 into 16.04 LTS

Tags: panel, ubuntu-studio

I installed (from scratch) Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS into one PC and all is fine, BUT... I don't have the old Panel 0 (superior edge of the screen).

Isn't it available into 16.04?

How can I get it?

[image]

Comment: you question is really vague... could you perhaps add a screenshot showing what "panel 0" is?

Comment: I uploaded an image. I'm talking about the superior edge panel (this image was take from a PC with Ubuntu Studio upgraded to 16.04, not from the scratch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click somewhere in your panel, select *Panel > Panel Preferences*, and you'll see your current panel is actually panel 0.  You can there configure your panel, and add new panels clicking on the "plus" sign; and add new items on your new panels with right click on it, and selecting *Panel > Add New Items*.

I suggest that you install xfce4-goodies (run in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install xfce4-goodies`) for some extra items to add to your panels.
This package will install the following Xfce4 related plugins:

- Extra artwork (xfce4-artwork)
- Battery levels monitor (xfce4-battery-plugin)
- Clipboard history (xfce4-clipman-plugin)
- CPU frequency management plugin (xfce4-cpufreq-plugin)
- CPU utilisation graphs (xfce4-cpugraph-plugin)
- Date and time plugin (xfce4-datetime-plugin)
- Disk performance display (xfce4-diskperf-plugin)
- Filesystem monitor (xfce4-fsguard-plugin)
- Generic monitor, for displaying any command result (xfce4-genmon-plugin)
- Mail watcher (xfce4-mailwatch-plugin)
- Mount plugin (xfce4-mount-plugin)
- Network load monitor (xfce4-netload-plugin)
- Notes plugin (xfce4-notes-plugin)
- Quick access to bookmarked folders, recent documents and removable
  media (xfce4-places-plugin)
- Tiny launchers (xfce4-quicklaunchers)
- Sensors plugin, frontend to lm-sensors (xfce4-sensors-plugin)
- Smartbookmarks plugin (xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin)
- System load monitor (xfce4-systemload-plugin)
- Timer plugin (xfce4-timer-plugin)
- Command line with history (xfce4-verve-plugin)
- Wireless lan monitor (xfce4-wavelan-plugin)
- Weather monitor (xfce4-weather-plugin)